# Ios - Change class implementation by updating the logic thru network and not submit new version

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

is it posible to change class implementation of submitted app thru the network ( i mean load the class on the fly at run time thru the network ) and not to submit the app with the new implementation as new version

if yes where i can see example how to do it

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you change your question to be about the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it is possible to do, but this is not permitted by Apple and would result in the app being rejected or pulled from the store.

Comment: @Eyeball, what about it? Standard `NSBundle` usage and limitations apply.